# HMACSHA1 equivalent in PHP

Tags: c#, php, encryption, output, sha1

I'm trying to do encryption using HMACSHA1 in both C# and PHP but I get different results. C# part is done. I want to make PHP part generate same result as C# part.

C#

```
     string key = "x94IudsnSUWCDSiSxRU5qDSRs88=";
     string text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

     HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1();
     hmac.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
     byte[] hashedData = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
     string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedData, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
     Console.WriteLine(WebUtility.UrlEncode(hash));
```

PHP

```
    $key = "x94IudsnSUWCDSiSxRU5qDSRs88=";
    $text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

    $hash = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $text, $key,true));
    echo urlencode($hash);
```

Results:
C#: `uAG0CDzyuEq7zbQ5ZfpVrb1ZUcA%3D`
PHP: `hx2c5SS6xI%2B8hQBoUqsWQT4KwP4%3D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to  base64decode the key in php before passing it to the hash_hmac function